# ¿Cómo editar bucle para que solo cambie el último dígito de un número?

Tags: python, bucles

```
import subprocess

ip = input("Introduce una ip excluyendo el ultimo octeto -->  ")

funciona=0
no_funciona=0

for funciona in range (0,10):
    ip = (ip + ".%d" % funciona)

    p = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-n', '1', '-w', '2', ip])

    p.wait()
```

El problema es que la ip es está sumando de esta manera = `192.168.1.1.0.1.2.3......255`
Alguien tiene la solución?

Comment: Deberías de formular mejor la pregunta para que podamos entender. ¿Qué intentas que haga tu código? Un ejemplo de como esperas que funcione nos ayudaría a entender tu problema.

Comment: ip = ip  ...... estas sobre escribiendo la variable. intentando cambiadole el nombre dentro del bucle :v

Comment: Es un problema de concepto. En ‘ip = (ip + ...)’ dentro del for estás uniendo un número a una cadena de texto. Básicamente estás haciendo ‘i = i +1’. Tampoco es una buena idea que declares dos variables que son diferentes con el mismo nombre porque la estás sobreescribiendo con el scope. Es decir, declaras e inicializas la variable ‘funciona = 0’ pero luego declaras otra con el mismo nombre con todos los valores de range(0,10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si he entendido bien lo que quieres hacer, te debería valer con sustituir estas dos líneas:

```
ip2 = (ip + ".%d" % funciona)

p = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-n', '1', '-w', '2', ip2])
```

El problema es que estás volviendo a definir la variable ip cada vez añadiéndole algo más al final, es decir, en la vuelta uno del bucle te toma el valor de la ip, en la vuelta dos, toma el valor del valor de la vuelta uno, en la vuelta tres el de la dos, y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Si señor, muchas gracias! Soy nuevo en esto y bueno, lo siento si mis preguntas son un poco estúpidas

Comment: No pidas perdón por no saber algo. Todos empezamos igual. Sigue aprendiendo y un día contestarás tú las preguntas como hicimos nosotros